# WCF Proxy creation

Tags: wcf, proxy

I have a question regarding WCF proxy creation, it may be of beginner level but have to ask. I created a proxy to a wcf service in my client using VS add service reference. Now because some methods in that service might take longer to execute and block all the proxy connection available i want to make call to each method using different proxy of the same service from my client.

Now the questions are:

1. Is my approach right, i mean will this solve my purpose?
2. For using different proxies do i need to add multiple service references with different names?
3. As a option to point 2 can i just add service reference once and replicate the same endpoint in config with different names? So every time i want to create a new proxy i pass in the name of a different endpoint to the same service in the constructor of the proxy?
4. Also is (multiple proxies = multiple instance of a proxy)?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use an asynchronous operations for the single proxy instance.
It's like the web browser - you can see the same webpage in many tabs. All of them are working independently but use the same endpoint resource. Try read [something like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. If something happens to that one proxy instance all the async calls will fail because the proxy is in a failed state.

Comment: Why can proxy fail? Application errors can be handled and it's ok. If channel is failed the other instances will also fail i suppose. Even if recreate an instance on fail only it's cheaper than do it for each service call.

Comment: If you have some smart proxy that can recreate the channel then fair it shouldn't be a problem. But proxies can fail for numerous reasons, which is why they have a Failed State built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single Service reference with a single configuration and a single endpoint. To call multiple methods on the service in parallel, you can create multiple proxy instances in different threads, or within different methods marked as `async`.

Comment: Hi Steve,Thanks for your response. I am not only concerned about making parallel calls but also about the connection pool exhaust. So if my proxy has a setting of say maxconnection=10  and if the method which blocks gets first 10 request then my connections are exhausted. Now if a request for another method that is not blocking comes in this request will not pass through to the service as the number of connections has exceed 10 already. Hope i am making sense , please correct me if i am missing a point here.

Comment: That makes sense, but if you base the value of your maxConnections setting and the resources available to your WCF service on the load the service has to handle, you can avoid that happening. You could also look at setting appropriate send and receive timeouts and set your system up to fail gracefully if something is taking too long.